# Aliexpress Login With Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, aliexpress

I want to login in aliexpress by using selenium. But i can't find element xpath of input email to send*keys. I try so many times by css*_selector, xpath, But it's not work.

This is my code:

```
driver.get("https://best.aliexpress.com")
time.sleep(5)
userinfo= driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.my-account--menuItem--1GDZChA")
userinfo.click()
login_button=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.my-account--menuText--1km-qni")
login_button.click()

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.cosmos-input-label").send_keys("test")
```

I want to send the email in right input email label

Answer (score 0):

here is you're path `//input[@class='cosmos-input']` you can use this to input you're email make sure first click on the signin button properly then the popup screen will be open and with the help of this xpath `//input[@class='cosmos-input']` you can use **send_keys** for inserting the email

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but im using this xpath, it's not work for my case

Comment: this is the way where you can create the xpath, but alibaba's site have dynamics id's and classes that's why it's change after reloading

Comment: Is there any way to find element of this login tag?

Answer (score 0):

You have this issue, because you rely on wrong element.

First, you should rely on input element and not on input label.

Second - sign in containers for different screen resolutions have different classes. `cosmos-input` class is not present for not maximized window, it's class is `comet-input`.

Unique attribute that is present in both cases is `[label=Email]`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://best.aliexpress.com")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
userinfo = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.my-account--menuItem--1GDZChA')))
userinfo.click()
login_button=driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"span.my-account--menuText--1km-qni")
login_button.click()

login = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[label=Email]')))

login.send_keys("test")
```

Comment: Hey @Yaroslavm, I know its funny!, After click on button "Login", Ali give a slide button to make a bot check. I'm detect that slide button and take an action click and hold. But it's not work. Do I detect wrong element of this slide button?

Comment: slider_container = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.fm-baxia-container") slider=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[aria-label=滑块]'))) actions.move_to_element(slider).click_and_hold().move_by_offset(slider_container.size['width'], 0).release().perform()